# Firebase Auth with Google Redirect back with error Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase-authentication

im using firebase auth with google and facebook, everything works but on iOS. i use remote debugging with safari and it returned me error `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured`. here is how i get my redirect result.

```
import {
        initializeApp
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.3.0/firebase-app.js";

    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "###",
        authDomain: "###",
        projectId: "###",
        storageBucket: "###",
        messagingSenderId: "###",
        appId: "###"
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    import {
        getAuth,
        getRedirectResult
    } from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/9.3.0/firebase-auth.min.js";

    const auth = getAuth();

    getRedirectResult(auth)
            .then((result) => {
                const user = result.user;
                // some codes
            }).catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                alert(errorMessage)
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering the error message "Right side of assignment cannot be destructured" while using Next.js with Firebase and the Google provider in Safari, you can try the following solution.

- Open the Next.js configuration file (next.config.js).
- Locate the following code snippet

```
config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(p => p.constructor.name !== 'UglifyJsPlugin')
config.plugins.push(new UglifyJsPlugin({
  parallel: true
}));
```

- Comment out the code by adding '//' in front of each line.
- Save the changes to the file.

Alternatively, you can use the minified version of the CDN instead of the un-minified version. This may resolve the issue without requiring any code changes.

If you continue to encounter issues, you may want to try updating your dependencies to the latest versions or seeking additional support from the community.